# How did Varys get there?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In S06E10 "The Winds of Winter", Lord Varys is first seen in Dorne in this scene:
[image]

And at the end of the episode Lord Varys is seen standing behind Daenerys in the ship:
[image]

How is this possible? Does Varys have some power that I am not aware of? What is it?